# 12 independent samples are "enough" in MCMC sampling for what?

Tags: sample-size, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm reading [Learning in Graphical Models (Jordan 1998)](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-94-011-5014-9) and in the chapter *Introduction to MCMC method* by D. J. C. Mackay (page 201) it says this:

[image]

It's not clear to me to what this is referring to. "We really only need about twelve independent samples" for what precisely?

*Add: I've found this particular chapter online [here](http://www.inference.org.uk/mackay/erice.pdf).*

Comment: This sounds meaningless from looking at the quoted passage only.

Comment: I tried to paste a significant portion, sorry. Not sure if I could paste more without infringing copyright .

Comment: I've found and added the chapter online @Xi'an, please see the updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this applies to a situation where you want to predict a future data point.

Let $X$ be a random variable, $\Phi=E[X]$ and $\sigma^2=Var(X)$ (in the notation of your screenshot, this corresponds to $\phi(x)=x$).

You get an estimator $\hat\Phi$ from $R$ independent samples, with $E[\hat\Phi]=\Phi$ and $Var(\hat\Phi)=\frac{\sigma^2}{R}$. You use $\hat\Phi$ as your prediction for the value of a future observation $\tilde X$. Your error can be measured by

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
E[(\tilde X-\hat\Phi)^2]&=&E[\tilde X^2]-2E[\tilde X]E[\hat\Phi]+E[\hat\Phi^2]\\
&=&E[\tilde X^2]-2\Phi^2+E[\hat\Phi^2]\\
&=&Var(\tilde X)+Var(\hat\Phi)\\
&=&\sigma^2\left(1+\frac{1}{R}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

In this situation, there is not much point in spending time and energy on getting $R$ large, since $Var(\tilde X)$ will dominate. The exact value of 12 is rather arbitrary.

This point does not hold if what you want to learn is $\Phi$ itself, in which case a larger sample would be needed (typically 100 or 1000).